# How to call Undo programmatically in Eclipse 4.x RCP application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

In an Eclipse RCP application we have coded some logic which under certain circumstances performs an undo of the last user operation. With Eclipse SDK 3.7.2 the following worked perfectly:

```java
IServiceLocator serviceLocator = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) serviceLocator.getService(ICommandService.class);
Command command = commandService.getCommand("org.eclipse.ui.edit.undo"); //$NON-NLS-1$
try {
    command.executeWithChecks(new ExecutionEvent());
} catch (NotDefinedException | NotEnabledException | NotHandledException | ExecutionException e) {
    logger.error("error executing command org.eclipse.ui.edit.undo", e);
}
```

After migrating the RCP application to Eclipse SDK 4.7.3a (Oxygen), the code above throws the following exception when executing the statement `command.executeWithChecks(new ExecutionEvent())`:

```
org.eclipse.core.commands.NotHandledException: There is no handler to execute for command org.eclipse.ui.edit.undo
        at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:507)
```

Inspecting the command object showed indeed that `command.isHandled()` and `command.getHandler().isHandled()` both return `false`, but we don't understand why: the active editor has focus and the undo button is enabled in the toolbar (i.e. it can be clicked).

We tried `command.getHandler().execute(new ExecutionEvent())` but it does nothing.

Does anyone know, what to do to call Undo from code with Eclipse SDK 4.x? Should we use another part of Eclipse API?

Comment: For the most part the 3.x compatability API in 4.x remains the same as in Eclipse 3.x. What editor is this?

Comment: The editor is from [uDIG](http://udig.refractions.net/): `MapEditorWithPalette`. It inherits from `org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.GraphicalEditorWithFlyoutPalette`

Comment: Well you will have to investigate how that editor implements Undo. Does it use an editor action contributor? Does that deal with the undo retargetable action?